# Splitting values from one column into multiple columns in SQL with different delimiters

Tags: sql-server

How to do this in SQL in any way possible?

Please see image or below:

```
||    Id    ||    Column1                      ||
||  1000    ||  SA(13), DS(1)                  ||
||  2000    ||  QW(1)                          ||
||  3000    ||  TE(23), RE(1), BB(40), VV(5)   ||
```

Result should be:

```
|| Id   ||  Column2    ||  Colum3  ||
|| 1000 ||    SA       ||    13    ||
|| 1000 ||    DS       ||     1    ||
|| 2000 ||    QW       ||     1    ||
|| 3000 ||    TE       ||    23    ||
|| 3000 ||    RE       ||     1    ||
|| 3000 ||    BB       ||    40    ||
|| 3000 ||    VV       ||     5    ||
```

[screenshot of the sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NHFz.png)

Comment: This shows a very poor database design :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in SQL Server is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id,
             left(column1, charindex(',', column1) - 1) as col23,
             substring(column1, charindex(',', column1) + 1) + ',' as rest
      from t
      union all
      select id,
             left(rest, charindex(',', rest) - 1) as col23
             substring(rest, charindex(',', rest) + 1) as rest
      from t
      where rest like '%,%'
     )
select id, left(col23, 2) as column2,
       replace(replace(substring(col23, 3, len(col23)), '(', ''), ')', '') as column3
from cte;
```

Note:  This assumes that `column2` has two characters (as in your example data).  If this can vary, you can also use `charindex()` to get split `col23`.

Comment: I got this error "Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function"

Comment: @drummerboi Here is a working version based on Gordon's answer: http://rextester.com/NDQ10805

Comment: @drummerboi Please remember to accept Gordon's answer as it has led you to your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a CSV Splitter function by Jeff Moden along with `left()` and `substring()`:

```
select 
    Id
 , col2 = left(x.Item,charindex('(',x.Item)-1)
 , col3 = substring(x.Item
          ,charindex('(',x.Item)+1
          ,charindex(')',x.Item)-charindex('(',x.Item)-1
          )
from t
  cross apply (
    select Item = ltrim(rtrim(i.Item))
      from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](t.col,',') as i
      ) x
```

returns:

test setup: http://rextester.com/IOKB65736

```
+------+------+------+
|  Id  | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1000 | SA   |   13 |
| 1000 | DS   |    1 |
| 2000 | QW   |    1 |
| 3000 | TE   |   23 |
| 3000 | RE   |    1 |
| 3000 | BB   |   40 |
| 3000 | VV   |    5 |
+------+------+------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Comment: These are great links!

Comment: Is there a query that does not need a function, I dont have an access for a function to run in our database

Comment: @drummerboi [Gordon Linoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42456086/2333499) does not require a function.